# Is it possible to convert a structure with a .stl file to a solid structure in Abaqus?

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis, design, abaqus

I have a **.stl** file of a structure and I want to use this file to do a simulation in Abaqus. **I need my part to be solid** but I don't have any .stp or .iges file of the sructure. So, I **imported my .stl file** via Plug-ins>>Tools>>STL Import and then I **converted meshes from tri to tet** (via mesh>>edit>>convert tri to tet)
I was wondering if this method is correct. I mean, is this the way to convert my part to solid? Because my simulation cannot be solved and I doubted if this was the problem since I just want to simulate a compression test which is too simple.

Comment: You can also try tools such as https://github.com/NicoSchlueter/Reverse

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a user of Abaqus, but take advantage of the hobbyist (free) version of Fusion 360. The program enables one to import a mesh file (STL) which one then converts to BREP. Once in BREP form, the many triangles of the typical STL file can be merged into a contiguous face (depending on the overall geometry).

Your question references having an STP file, which Fusion 360 will export. If you require the STP file to accomplish your goal, the objective may be reached in this manner.

Consider also that STL files may not be manifold and if so, will not properly process in many ways other than that which you describe.